# "return" asynchronous data using Observables

Tags: angular, observable, rxjs5

Say I have this in my HTML:

```
  <div>
    <mat-label>Matched events count: {{(getMatchedEventsCount() | async)?}}</mat-label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <mat-label>Total events count: {{(getTotalEventsCount() | async)?}}</mat-label>
  </div>
```

my question is, what do I return (as far as an Observable) from these helper methods?

```
  getMatchedEventsCount(){
    return Observable.of(3);
  }

  getTotalEventsCount(){
    return Observable.of(5);
  }
```

but my question is - how can we do something actually asynchronous?

At the moment, I am getting this HTML parse error though:

> Uncaught Error: Template parse errors: Parser Error: Unexpected end of
>   expression: Matched events count: {{(getMatchedEventsCount() |
>   async)?}} at the end of the expression [Matched events count:
>   {{(getMatchedEventsCount() | async)?}}] in
>   ng:///AppModule/EventsListComponent.html@40:21 ("
>           
>           
>             [ERROR ->]Matched events count: {{(getMatchedEventsCount() | async)?}}
>           
>           "): ng:///AppModule/EventsListComponent.html@40:21 Parser Error: Conditional expression (getMatchedEventsCount() | async)?
>   requires all 3 expressions at the end of the expression [Matched
>   events count: {{(getMatchedEventsCount() | async)?}}] in
>   ng:///AppModule/EventsListComponent.html@40:21 ("
>           
>           
>             [ERROR ->]Matched events count: {{(getMatchedEventsCount() | async)?}}
>           
>           "): ng:///AppModule/EventsListComponent.html@40:21

Comment: You can't use the `?` in this way; you would have to get do property access after the `?`. Try removing `?`

Comment: The template parse error has naught to do with the return of the methods.. it would be the same regardless of the results returned. Same difference as other compile time vs. run-time errors..

Comment: ok I will try removing the `?` character

Comment: yes it looks like that worked, can you add an answer and explain why that is?

Comment: also, in your answer, if you can explain how to use a Subscription to load the data instead of an Obersvable, that's useful too...

Comment: @AlexanderMills can you add your reason for why you use `?` there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I notice that you have already troubleshooted the `?` in the comment thread. The reason the `?` (called the ["save navigation operator"](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#the-safe-navigation-operator----and-null-property-paths)) does not work there is that it is guarding against `null` and `undefined` values in *property* paths, meaning you need to attempt to access a property after using the `?`. Right now you are trying to use it retroactively to see if an object is `null` or `undefined`, but it can only look forward into the object, not backwards, and it needs a property to look for.

You are correct that you should return an `Observable` from the methods and give that to the `async` pipe. Here is some documentation on the `async` pipe just to be thorough: https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe.

As to your question in the comment thread about how to use a `Subscription` to load the data instead of an `Observable`...

You can do that using the `subscribe` method and assigning the data to a property on your component, like so:

```
matchedEventsSub: Subscription;
matchedEventsCount: number;

getMatchedEventsCount() {
  this.matchedEventsSub = Observable.of(3).subscribe(value => {
    this.matchedEventsCount = value;
  });
}
```

Note that `subscribe`ing to an `Observable` returns a `Subscription`. Then you must remember to `unsubscribe` from that subscription in your `OnDestroy` lifecycle hook to prevent memory leaks:

```
ngOnDestroy() {
  if (this.matchedEventsSub) { this.matchedEventsSub.unsubscribe(); }
}
```

As you can imagine, this becomes cumbersome when you have 2, 3, 10 subscriptions in one component. That's why the Angular team created the `async` pipe.

Finally,

> how can we do something actually asynchronous?

It's actually quite simple. Let's say you have an `EventsService` that you inject into your component:

```
constructor(private eventsService: EventService) {}
```

That service may encapsulate an `Http` request or something -- Angular's `HttpClient` module uses `Observable`s to represent asynchronous data. You could use your `EventsService` to get your asynchronous stream of events like this:

```
matchedEventsCount$: Observable<number>;

getMatchedEventsCount(): Observable<number> {
  const allEvents$ = this.eventsService.getEvents();
  return allEvents$.map(events => events.length);
}
```

Call the method in your `OnInit` lifecycle hook to populate your data:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.getMatchedEventsCount();
}
```

And then display it in your template:

```
<h1>Events: {{ matchedEventsCount$ | async }}</h1>
```